# Audio Unit for play and record without filters

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit

I'm developing an app that sets an audio unit to record and play that use a callback for audio processing. I use a callback because I have to implement my own filters in c. I'm using an Audio Unit with kAudioUnitType_Output and kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO. This Audio Unit uses a High Pass filter by default. I only want to apply my own filters so I wanted to know if there is a way to disable this filters without setting the audio session mode to AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement because I loss gain using it. 
I couldn't find a way to disable this filters or a Audio Unit that could use for this objetive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to do it without using measurement mode.  I compensate for the gain loss by just boosting the gain (4x) manually in a render callback.

Comment: I try something similar but I'm having howling problems with this solution.

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: If I boost the gain manually I'm experiencing acoustic feedback when I'm recording and playing in real time with the app.

Comment: I think the feedback is a result of the gain and the proximity of the microphone to the speaker, not the method of achieving the gain.

Comment: You are right it's a physics problem  but I don't know how the Audio Unit with kAudioUnitType_Output and kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO can give the same gain but without feedback having the same proximity between the microphone and the speaker.

Comment: Could be the high pass filter,  or maybe the automatic gain control that's enabled without measurement mode that's preventing feedback.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same but I wanted to confirm it with some one with more experience. I have one last question. Did you compensate the gain loose by boosting the gain (4x) because you measure the output or why?